# I don't want it to take action when I click on the element of the page that is open in the BottomNavigation menu

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation menu, I can switch between pages with it, but let's say the home page is open and when I select it from the menu again, it opens the page again. I do not want this.

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.preparing_fragment)
bottomMenuBar.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

What should I do